# wss_content database is getting created in a different folder

Tags: 2013, 2010, 2016

I have configured my SQL server to create new databases in E Drive

I created a new DB from SQL and it works fine

But when I map this DB server to sharepoint, SharePoint creates its wss_content database in D drive

How can I change this?

Comment: Is your SharePoint installation drive is D?

Comment: Have you restarted SQL instance after changing default DB location? If I remember correctly those changes take effect after Instance restart.

Comment: Yes that was the mistake, we restarted the DB server in SQL management studio 2012 and 2008 and it worked